# Facebook API, Unity3D. Can't get user's email

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get user's email using FB.API() method, all code is below

```
public class FacebookCase : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    FB.Init(new Facebook.InitDelegate(initComplete), null, null);
}

private void initComplete()
{
    FB.Login("email,publish_actions", new Facebook.FacebookDelegate(loginComplete));
}

private void loginComplete(FBResult result)
{
    FB.API("/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, graphCallback);
}

private void graphCallback(FBResult result)
{
    Debug.Log(result.Text);
}
```

}

That code gives me first and last name, but instead of email address I've got 'id=2385905023865'.
Why it so? How to get email?

Answer (score 0):

The `id` field is always returned. It's not shown "instead" of the `email` field. My suspicion is that you didn't request the `email` permission properly during login. Please check accordingly...

Comment: But I do request of the email in this string    `FB.Login("email,publish_actions", new Facebook.FacebookDelegate(loginComplete));`

Comment: You you inspected the the Access Token so that it really contains the `email` permission? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Yeah, you are right, i have to do something with Access Token, i have realized it already, thank you xD

Comment: But I have one more question. How to extend Scopes of Access Token? I need it to test my app

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean with extend? And what about testing?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I meant - how to gain more permissions for Access Token? But it's done already :3

Comment: Add more to the `scope` parameter. But watch out, extended permissions are bound for Login Review. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Login